# Avoid onRowClick event when outputLink is clicked inside of RichFaces datatable

Tags: javascript, dom-events, richfaces

How to avoid the call to `onRowClick` on the datatable on the column that has the outputlink (target to a new window)?

```
<rich:dataTable id="dt" value="#{bean.cars} var="_car">
    <a:support event="onRowClick" action="#{action.navigateToCarDetails(_car.id)}"/>

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Select</f:facet>
        <a:commandLink onclick="Event.stop(event)" action="#{bean.toggleSelectedCar(_car.id)}" reRender="dt" ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true">                
            <h:graphicImage value="/img/icon_checkbox_#{bean.isCarSelected(_car.id) ? 'active' : 'inactive'}.gif"/>
        </a:commandLink>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Brand</f:facet>
        <h:outputLink value="#{_car.link}" target="_blank">
            <h:outputText value="#{_car.brand}"/>
        </h:outputLink>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Year</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{_car.year}"/>
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Color</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{_car.color}"/>
    </rich:column>

</rich:dataTable>
```

So with the sample above, when I click on the row, it will navigate to a page with the detail of the Car.

And when clicked on the Select column's row, it will update the selected car, and update the checkbox icon accordingly, but without navigate to the car detail page, because I have the `onclick="Event.stop(event)"`.

But when I click on the outputLink box, other than opening a new window and show the manufacturer web page, it also update the original page to the car details.  How do I prevent this from happening? (I tried adding the `onclick` event stop just like the select column, but other than stopping the `onrowclick` event, it also block the link to the manufacturer web page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what `Event.stop(event)` does is the following:

```
\\ stops the event from bubbling up the event chain
event.stopPropagation();

\\ prevents the default action the browser makes on that event
event.preventDefault();
```

In your case you want just to prevent bubbling, so a way to go:

```
onclick="event.stopPropagation()"
```

Comment: this works!
so I did this

`
<rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Brand</f:facet>
        <h:outputLink onclick="event.stopPropagation()" value="#{_car.link}" target="_blank">
            <h:outputText value="#{_car.brand}"/>
        </h:outputLink>
    </rich:column>
`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
<rich:dataTable
    onRowClick="if (event.target.id.endsWith('columnId')) return false;" …>
```

the onRowClick function is executed before the `a4j:support` so if you return false the action won't be called.

Comment: the onRowClick in dataTable actually completely replaced the a4j:onRowClick, I check the generated code

with the a4j:onRowClick, I get a <tr onclick=....>
but when the onRowClick is added to dataTable, the <tr onlcick=...>
changed to the statement specified there.

so the naviagte to car detail page no longer work even on other columns.